# In which format is the access_token

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0

My Token provider is issuing an OAuth2 token having the following format. "AT-123..."

[image]

I cannot decode and identify the format..how my resource server will decode it ?

It was issued using the following json:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access tokens don't have to be readable (see [OAuth2 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.4)). They can be just some random identifiers for your OAuth2 server. Your resource server can use the token introspection endpoint of your OAuth2 server (see [respective RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662)) to get information about the token. The introspection endpoint URL can be found in the OAuth2 server discovery document found at `/.well-known/openid-configuration` path (e.g. this is [Google's discovery document](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)).

But many OAuth2 servers use JWT format for their access tokens, so they can be validated offline (if you don't need to check their possible invalidation) a they contain useful info.